# Lightning Web Component Development: I am having data format issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Lightning Web Component Development: I am having data format issue

```
<lightning:input name="input1" label="Enter a date" type="date" datestyle="short" />
```

or datestyle="medium" or datestyle="long"

This date is getting changed based on the LOCALE of the user profile. Please do suggest the data format shouldn't change based on the LOCALE as i am using  datestyle="short".

Comment: Its it Aura or LWC? `lightning:input` feels aura?

Comment: Pranay : Its in LWC

Comment: Wont it be `lightning-input` then?

Comment: This is what i am using <lightning:input name="input1" label="Enter a date" type="date" datestyle="short" />, this being an AURA, then date is getting changed based on the LOCALE of the user profile. Even i change the LOCALE for the userprofile that dataformat should remain my custom. DO i need to do anything additional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `date-style="short"` in LWC or `dateStyle="short"` in AURA, `datestyle="short"` will not work in LWC.

Always check in the component specifications, like [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much Matias. I am able to use the date-style="short". But when the data format is being controlled by LOCALE of the userprofile, which still don't fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. The `datestyle` property is still locale-aware. For example, in the US you would get `12/31/2020` but in Europe you would get `31/12/2020`.

From the docs:

> Dates are displayed by default in a medium-length style, such as Jan 7, 2019 in the en-US locale.

The wording "in the en-US" locale implies that the style would look different for other locales, but it would still be "Medium", as opposed to "short" (only numbers) or "long" (full date)

Full Information is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation)